How to generate STRH instruction instead of STRH.W GHS compiler for ARM Cortex-M7 processor?
I am currently working on interfacing an external flash memory S26H in XIP mode (by directly dereferencing the memory addresses) which has the restriction that all memory accesses must be 2-byte aligned. At the following instruction, the controller goes into an IMPRECISERR bus exception:
strh.w r0, [r2, #0xAAA] ;r0 =0x1234, r2= 0x60000000 for example

what I find surprising here is that the address 0x60000AAA is a 2-byte aligned address, it still leads to an alignment error raised by the memory interface in the micro-controller.
On a code compiled in a different environment, I did not find this problem. The only difference seems to be that in the working code, the instruction used is strh instead of strh.w. In both cases, the compiler was the same i.e. GHS.
How do I force the assembler to generate this instruction?

IMPRECISERR is async, are you really sure it's this instruction? Why?

The 16-bit strh or strh.n instruction is generated if the displacement is sufficiently small.  Try adding 0xAAA to R2 beforehand and then just do strh r0, [r2].

According to the documentation, strh supports unaligned accesses. The source of IMPRECISERR is another instruction.

so the exception is triggered by the memory interface engine in the controller which is why it manifests as IMPRECISERR later. I can already see the alignment error flag set in the memory interface registers immediately after this instruction. I am not 100% sure that this error is due to the strh instruction, which is why I would like to understand if there is a way to force the assembler to alter the instruction.

Please provide a [mre] with the complete assembly. -- While waiting for comments and answers, please look up the instructions you see as problem, and add your findings to the question. Especially focus on the difference and tell us why you think it matters.
